# Alignment issue on some of the site's flag summary page

Tags: bug, design, flag-history

There is an alignment issue in the Flag summary page of some of the Stack Exchange sites.

Previously the vote count and the question title were displayed on the same line. Now the question title is displaying on the next line.

Sample screenshots were taken from the DBA, Stack Apps, Super User, and Movies & TV Stack Exchange sites. On some other sites also this issue can be reproduced.

> [image: Some of the SE sites]

On Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow there isn't any alignment issue:

> [image: Meta SE]

Answer (score 2):

So, what do all of those broken sites have in common?

[image: border]

[image: right border]

[image: Right Border]

[image: RIGHT BORDER]

A 1px right border! Which is just enough reduction to the width of the main content area to prevent the fixed-width score and title from coexisting on the same line.

#### Recommended fix

We *could* reduce the fixed with of the title a bit.

Or, we could redesign the flag area to be properly responsive and scale smoothly to the window size.